# Google map marker description

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, coordinates, marker

im using google map with coordinate but the marker description is show coordinate , can i setting marker description with text we want ?

```html
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=51.509865,-0.118092&z=18&output=embed" width="360" height="270" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

[Here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZzDw.png)

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done as the place card's function is to show the name/info of the point of interest that is currently selected. Since your case is not a POI, it is only returning the coordinates of the plotted marker.

An alternative would be to use the Maps JavaScript API with [InfoWindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).

Or try to add the point of interest using the "Add a missing place" feature in [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps).